# Password_hash is not working Strangely

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This always works

```
public function hash($password)
    {   
        $password1 = "123456";
        return password_hash($password1,PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
    }
```

This never works

```
 public function hash($password)
    {    
        return password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
    }
```

Can some Body Enlighten me Where is the problem ?
Password_verify verifies first but not second i have done var_dump on $password and every thing returns fine.

Comment: is `$password` defined elsewhere?

Comment: yes It is passing on to its function

Comment: $password also has 123456 on var_dump

Comment: This code is in cakePHP src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php

Comment: How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here  was if cakePHP  calling hash function  twice in $this->Users->save() . So $password was getting rehashed and then storing while $password1="1234567" always remain same when it was getting rehashed.

I am really sorry that i bothered people. thanks @Rinsad and @Javier for trying such  question and giving precious time to me.

Answer (score 0):

Remember hash($var1,$var2) is a php function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). If you write a function with the same name you will end up with the following error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hash()
```

Use a different name like

```
public function hash_new($password)
{    
    return password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
}
```

Comment: In the first example, how do you call the function? As the parameter is already hardcoded you have nothing to pass right?

Comment: its cake PHP core file its in a class and will always be called as $this->hash even if parameter is hardcoded we still pass the parameter

Answer (score -1):

hash() is a PHP function, so you shouldn't use it as a  name for a custom function. Try using another name.

Also, hashing with PASSWORD_BCRYPT has a different behaviour in PHP 7.0+ compared to previous versions

In older versions:
PASSWORD_BCRYPT has an optional salt parameter. You can use the same salt always so hashing the same string will render the exact same result every time. 
If you omitted the salt parameter, you'll get a random salt and every hashing of the same string will produce a different output.

In PHP 7.0+, the salt parameter was eliminated so you'll always get a random salt, hence a different output every time.

Comment: first example is already working so there is no question of hash function not working.also for PHP 7.0

Comment: I don't agree with your opening line. Their code works and that function isn't reserved. I agree it isn't a good idea, but that is irrelevant to the question.